# Cutting multimedia files based on start and end time using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to cut the video using the start and end time of the video by using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -i movie.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -async 1 cut.mp4
```

By using the above command I want to cut the video from `00:00:03` to `00:00:08`. But it is not cutting the video between those times instead of that it is cutting the video with first 11 seconds.

Comment: Your full, uncut ffmpeg console output is missing. Please always include this when asking. Thanks.

Comment: You should either use `-t 00:00:05` or `-to 00:00:08` in order to cut the video from 00:00:03 to 00:00:08. Check out the documentation.

Answer (score 842, accepted):

You probably do not have a keyframe at the 3 second mark.  Because non-keyframes encode differences from other frames, they require all of the data starting with the previous keyframe.

With the mp4 container it is possible to cut at a non-keyframe without re-encoding using an edit list.  In other words, if the closest keyframe before 3s is at 0s then it will copy the video starting at 0s and use an edit list to tell the player to start playing 3 seconds in.

If you are using the [latest ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) from git master it will do this using an edit list when invoked using the command that you provided.  If this is not working for you then you are probably either using an older version of ffmpeg, or your player does not support edit lists.  Some players will ignore the edit list and always play all of the media in the file from beginning to end.

If you want to cut precisely starting at a non-keyframe and want it to play starting at the desired point on a player that does not support edit lists, or want to ensure that the cut portion is not actually in the output file (for example if it contains confidential information), then you can do that by re-encoding so that there will be a keyframe precisely at the desired start time.  Re-encoding is the default if you do not specify `copy`.  For example:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -async 1 cut.mp4
```

When re-encoding you may also wish to include additional quality-related options or a particular AAC encoder.  For details, see ffmpeg's [x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for video and [AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) for audio.

Also, the `-t` option specifies a duration, not an end time.  The above command will encode 8s of video starting at 3s.  To start at 3s and end at 8s use `-t 5`.  If you are using a current version of ffmpeg you can also replace `-t` with `-to` in the above command to end at the specified time.

Comment: Is there a shortcut to specify till the end of the video?

Comment: @JikkuJose: Omit the `-t`/`-to` and its argument to continue to the end.

Comment: Note: it is faster to supply `-ss` BEFORE the input file (before `-i`), because that way ffmpeg will skip directly to the location. However, that will also set the time "zero" to that location, meaning that `-to` will point to the wrong time. Source: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking

Comment: I get audio and video sync issue after using this ```ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -async 1 cut.mp4``` , though the original file has no such issue.

Comment: @user2002522: Try without the `-async 1`.

Comment: this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14013439/1170023 is what you want for finding the keyframe times with -c copy to avoid audio sync

Comment: Remember to put both `-ss` and `-t` before `-i` to avoid black screen for few seconds at the beginning and don't use `-to` because it will produce a file with incorrect duration.

Comment: I also experienced sync issues. i tried the solution provided by George Chalhoub (below) and the sync issue was fixed

Comment: i am getting quality issue. Is there anyone getting same issue ?

Comment: @MuhammedYalçınKuru: To control the quality see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

Comment: @mark4o i have tried with my lack of info. Didn't find fit one. while cutting passed this one ` -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 `

Comment: Is there any way to re-encode only the part up to next keyframe, then copy everything else over?

Comment: In layman's terms what does now deprecated `async 1` does?

Comment: Hi guys, I've implement it on my Android app, but it seem have a bit inaccuracy. I used this command `ffmpeg -y -i movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:00.400 -to 00:00:47 -preset ultrafast -c:v copy -c:a copy cut.mp4` the result always have the duration 46s, that mean it always cut 1s instead of 400ms as the params above. It can work well on my iOS app. Someone can help me in this case?

Comment: @EmBeCoRau If you want to re-encode the video in order to create a new keyframe at a precise time, remove the -c:v copy option.

Answer (score 1362):

The fastest and best ffmpeg-based method I have figured out is:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -to 00:02:00 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

**This command trims your video in seconds!**

---

Explanation of the command:

| Command | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| **-i** | This specifies the input file. In that case, it is (input.mp4). |
| **-ss** | Used with -i, this seeks in the input file (input.mp4) to position. |
| **00:01:00** | This is the time your trimmed video will start with. |
| **-to** | This specifies duration from start (00:01:00) to end (00:02:00). |
| **00:02:00** | This is the time your trimmed video will end with. |
| **-c copy** | This is an option to trim via stream copy. (NB: Very fast) |

The timing format is `hh:mm:ss`.

---

Please note that the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18449609/365102) highly upvoted answer forces a reencode, and so the trim would be extremely slow. For more information, look at this official ffmpeg [article](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Cuttingsmallsections).

Comment: You may still suffer from a lack of keyframes with this though. I took your approach to cutting, then re-encoded as per the accepted answer to make sure I minimised the amount of time I needed to spend re-encoding.

Comment: As @pelson says, this will cut off key frames and leave the first few seconds blank (if the cutting time is between key frames). Interestingly, changing the parameter order solves the problem: `ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -to 00:02:00 -i input.mp4 -ss 00:01:00 -to 00:02:00  -c copy output.mp4`. Now, however, skipping is broken and the end time is not correct (in my case).

Comment: According to [FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking), input seeking is now both fast and accurate, is there any specific reason you use output seeking instead of input seeking?

Comment: Nice! What worked for me was `ffmpeg -i origin.mp4 -ss 02:51:14 -c copy destination.mp4` (I guess `-to` is optional and unnecessary if you want the end point to be the absolute end of the video.)

Comment: For me also, the output was corrupted and with no sound. IINA player is crashing whenever I'm trying to open the video. I'm on macOS 10.13.5 and ffmpeg is 3.4

Comment: You should use this answer if you don't need to trim at an exact milisecond, thus it will select the closest keyframe available. That's why it's so fast, it selects the closest keyframes and takes the snippet out without the need of reencoding. However, if you do need a precise time, taking the nearest keyframe isn't enough, because it certainly won't match exactly. The only solution available is to reencode the video, and that's why it's so slow. That's the only solution, though, if you do need this. That's why the other answer should be the accepted one, as that's what was OP's issue about.

Comment: You probably want `-ss` *and* `-to` before `-i`, example: `ffmpeg -ss aa:bb:cc -to xx:yy:zz -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4`.  Otherwise the `-to` value ends up being a duration instead of the end time from the original video.  Omitting the `-c copy` will make it slower and more accurate by re-encoding, but still faster than if the `-ss` and `-to` are specified after `-i`, since that case means to trim after having to process the whole input file.

Comment: @theferrit32 it gives `Option to (record or transcode stop time) cannot be applied to input url file.mp4 -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.`

Comment: Note that if you specify `-ss` before `-i` only, the timestamps will be reset to zero, so `-t` and `-to` have not the same effect. If you want to keep the original timestamps, add the `-copyts` option. [Reference](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Cuttingsmallsections)

Comment: `-to` is not the duration, `-t` is !

Comment: I can confirm that with the -c copy the speed is more than 300 times of normal playing speed whereas without the -c copy the speed is only 4 times of the normal playing speed. As typing the comment, the "with c " command has finished, and the "without c " is still running....

Comment: This one is outdated, unless there are differences between the win and linux builds, or the answer was made with an old version of ffmpeg, but placing -to after the input file, for my recent win build, it creates an unwanted output, as in it resets timestamps with -ss to 0 and -to won't actually end with the desired timestamp from the input file. The -ss and -to options need to be placed before the input... for new versions of ffmpeg. Otherwise, -ss -i input should be followed by -t, i.e. total duration of the clip, to achieve the right duration for the cut.

Comment: I would advise to put the from time and to time together, otherwise they might not cut properly. So it should be: ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -to 00:02:00 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4

Comment: IMHO you should fix your answer and put the start/to options on one side of the input -- either left or right. Splitting them gives very counter-intuitive behavior because as you put it "-to" behaves like "-t" (because it counts output time). I just learned about it from https://superuser.com/a/670574/43045

Comment: This is so fast! I'm never gonna use the regular windows photo editor

Comment: in batches `for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30  -i "$f" -c copy "$f".mp4 ; done`

Comment: and optimize compression H265 `for f in *.mp4 ; do ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -i "$f" -c:v libx265 -preset fast -crf 28 -tag:v hvc1 -c:a eac3 -b:a 224k "$f".mp4 ; done`

Comment: You wrote _"from start (00:01:40) to end (00:02:12)"_ when the `-ss` is set to `00:01:00` (not `00:01:40`) and the `-to` is set to `00:02:00` (not `00:02:12`). Is there something I'm missing? Some explanation for why there is a discrepancy, if that's not a simple mistake, would greatly enhance your answer.

Comment: We need a a way SO to replace accepted answers which are out of date.

Comment: This worked but it removed the subtitles from the output file.

Comment: @Yamaneko If you need to cut at an exact millisecond, but do not want to waste time reencoding a large portion of the file, I have found it useful to cut from the needed start time to the next timeframe (often a multiple of 2 seconds), and then combine that with a second video file cut from the keyframe to the required end time. You can transcode both files into TS format and simply append them to merge the two cuts, remuxing with ffmpeg if a different output format is necessary.

Answer (score 119):

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -async 1 -c copy cut.mp4
```

Use **-c copy** for make in instantly. In that case ffmpeg will not re-encode video, just will cut to according size.

Comment: of -c copy works great, but only if I remove -async 1

Comment: This ends up failing on write due to invalid headers in the case of different input and output containers e.g. .mkv input and .mp4 output.

Comment: Alright, to convert .mkv to .mp4 you have to use another command: `ffmpeg -i movie.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy converted_movie.mp4` and vise versa

Comment: What are the advantages of re-encoding? Is it of any use if we just want smaller video in the same format?

Comment: I have same question as @Harsha. What does -c copy in layman's terms?

Comment: @SudhirSinghKhanger Just found a free GUI interface to Ffmpeg, check out the program LosslessCut

Comment: -t is not picked up and the command ends up cutting from -ss to and of file

Comment: if we use -t it will clip the video till the end of the video. Try -to instead of -t

Comment: Adding `-c copy` apparently make the first few frames corrupted, so I removed that and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 56):

Here's what I use and will only take a **few seconds** to run:

```sh
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 01:19:27 -to 02:18:51 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Reference: [Trim video files using FFmpeg](https://www.arj.no/2018/05/18/trimvideo) by *Alexander Refsum Jensenius*.

---

Generated `mp4` files could also be used in `iMovie`. More info related to get the full duration using [get_duration(input_video)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62516360/2402577) model.

If you want to concatenate multiple cut scenes you can use following Python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

def get_duration(input_video):
    cmd = ["ffprobe", "-i", input_video, "-show_entries", "format=duration",
           "-v", "quiet", "-sexagesimal", "-of", "csv=p=0"]
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()


def main():
    name = "input.mkv"
    times = []
    times.append(["00:00:00", "00:00:10"])
    times.append(["00:06:00", "00:07:00"])
    # times = [["00:00:00", get_duration(name)]]
    if len(times) == 1:
        time = times[0]
        cmd = ["ffmpeg", "-i", name, "-ss", time[0], "-to", time[1], "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "copy", "output.mp4"]
        subprocess.check_output(cmd)
    else:
        open('concatenate.txt', 'w').close()
        for idx, time in enumerate(times):
            output_filename = f"output{idx}.mp4"
            cmd = ["ffmpeg", "-i", name, "-ss", time[0], "-to", time[1], "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "copy", output_filename]
            subprocess.check_output(cmd)

            with open("concatenate.txt", "a") as myfile:
                myfile.write(f"file {output_filename}\n")

        cmd = ["ffmpeg", "-f", "concat", "-i", "concatenate.txt", "-c", "copy", "output.mp4"]
        output = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
        print(output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example script will cut and merge scenes in between `00:00:00 - 00:00:10` and `00:06:00 - 00:07:00`.

---

If you want to cut the complete video (in case if you want to convert `mkv` format into `mp4`) just uncomment the following line:

```py
# times = [["00:00:00", get_duration(name)]]
```

Comment: Couldn't this just use "-c" with "copy" instead of splitting out -c:v and -c:a?

Comment: I don't know why but I'm getting error with this code

Comment: this is slow. the input file isn't being seeked, it's being processed and discarded. -ss as an output option = slow. see my updated answer.

Comment: I'm getting the video cutted but for first seconds the frames just freeze

Comment: @PabloDíaz The video you are using might be faulty. Can you give it a try with a different video uncommenting `# times = [["00:00:00", get_duration(name)]]` and see if the generated `output.mp4` file is fine

Comment: @yo  It shouldn't be slow. What do you mean by `input file isn't being seeked? Instead of input.mp4` provide the path of the movie you want to convert. I have tried to convert 6.7 GB BlueRay movie by the script I provided, which only took 3.56 seconds.

Answer (score 38):

```
    ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -vf trim=3:8 cut.mp4
```

Drop everything except from second 3 to second 8.

Comment: I get the first 8 seconds with this, with the first 3 seconds frozen on the first frame. Fixed by chaining `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS` filter after the trim filter.

Comment: This says "The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it." Adding -strict -2 does not help. The result is a zero length file.

Comment: @Ivan, did you try adding `-strict -2` before `cut.mp4` (as opposed to the end of the command line)?

Comment: THis is super slow

Answer (score 30):

## new answer (fast)

You can make bash do the math for you, and it works with milliseconds.

```
toSeconds() {
    awk -F: 'NF==3 { print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 } NF==2 { print ($1 * 60) + $2 } NF==1 { print 0 + $1 }' <<< $1
}

StartSeconds=$(toSeconds "45.5")
EndSeconds=$(toSeconds "1:00.5")
Duration=$(bc <<< "(${EndSeconds} + 0.01) - ${StartSeconds}" | awk '{ printf "%.4f", $0 }')
ffmpeg -ss $StartSeconds -i input.mpg -t $Duration output.mpg
```

This, like the old answer, will produce a 15 second clip. This method is ideal even when clipping from deep within a large file because seeking isn't disabled, unlike the old answer. And yes, I've verified it's frame perfect.

**NOTE:** The start-time is *INCLUSIVE* and the end-time is normally *EXCLUSIVE*, hence the `+0.01`, to make it inclusive.

If you use `mpv` you can enable millisecond timecodes in the OSD with `--osd-fractions`

---

## old answer with explanation (slow)

To cut based on start and end time from the source video and avoid having to do math, **specify the end time as the input option and the start time as the output option.**

```
ffmpeg -t 1:00 -i input.mpg -ss 45 output.mpg
```

This will produce a 15 second cut from 0:45 to 1:00.

This is because when `-ss` is given as an output option, the discarded time is still included in the total time read from the input, which `-t` uses to know when to stop. Whereas if `-ss` is given as an *input* option, the start time is seeked and *not counted*, which is where the confusion comes from.

It's slower than seeking since the omitted segment is still processed before being discarded, but this is the only way to do it as far as I know. If you're clipping from deep within a large file, it's more prudent to just do the math and use `-ss` for the input.

Comment: slow, but the only thing worked for me (without loosing frames from other answers)

Comment: Excelent. The only solution to not calculate duration but provide start and end to the ffmpeg

Comment: As of Aug 3, 2022, the old (slow) answer is the only one that works for me. The other answers produce a video where the timestamps are messed up and when I try to concatenate the parts, I get a totally messed up video.

Answer (score 7):

Use -to instead of -t: -to specifies the end time, -t specifies the duration

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ceremcem/4c7b44edd6c21c873f7f27bdaf7f2baa

Answer (score 3):

My setup:

```
$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
```

I found that the order of the switches matters.
If `-i` is not between `-ss` and `-t` then I got about 3-seconds leading blank in the result.

So whatever additional switches you use, make sure you got those three switches in the correct order, like this

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:03 -i movie.mp4 -t 00:00:08 cut.mp4
```

Answer (score 3):

I was interested in cut times based on milliseconds, and noticed that seconds (and fractions of them) can be specified for the cut as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 17.5 -to 20.5 output.mp4
```

For a duration rather than an end time, use `-t` instead of `-to`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 17.5 -t 3 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

feel free to use this tool https://github.com/rooty0/ffmpeg_video_cutter I wrote awhile ago
Pretty much that's cli front-end for ffmpeg... you just need to create a yaml what you want to cut out... something like this

```
cut_method: delete  # we're going to delete following video fragments from a video
timeframe:
  - from: start   # waiting for people to join the conference
    to: 4m
  - from: 10m11s  # awkward silence
    to: 15m50s
  - from: 30m5s   # Off-Topic Discussion
    to: end
```

and then just run a tool to get result

Comment: Going by the GitHub account profile, it looks like this might be a tool that you've created yourself. If this is the case, [you *must* disclose this in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), otherwise this can be considered spam.

Answer (score 1):

First, a video should be coded using ffvhuff encoder so that the video could be cut to exactly at the start and end time. Normally, with other commands given above, it may be possible that the video is not cut to the specific duration as not every frame is an intra coded frame.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:03:00 -i input_file.mkv -t 00:01:19 -c:v ffvhuff -pix_fmt yuv420p -y output_file.mkv
```

Comment: For cases like not landing on an intra coded frame, would the idea be to seek backward to an iframe or something?

Comment: Yes, you could do it. But you need to do additional analysis like finding out the intra-period. So, it is better to encode a video using FFvhuff and then cut it.

Answer (score 1):

Using ffmpeg-python library i did it this way.. but you must uninstall ffmpeg before installing ffmpeg-library.. see my github for more details.
https://github.com/johntsunami/ffmpeg-python-video-trimmer/blob/main/trimmer.py

```
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\johnc\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin")
stream = ffmpeg.input(r"C:/Users/johnc/Desktop/krystal.mp4",ss=57, t=55)  # ss is start time,  t IS DURATION

## SEPARATES AUDIO AND VIDEO INDEPENDENTLY BECAUSE SOMETIMES IT DOESNT HAVE AUDIO UNLESS YOU DO THIS>

audio = stream.audio 
video = stream.video   #.trim(start=60,end=115).filter('setpts','PTS-STARTPTS') ## CURRENTLY IS GOOD BUT DOESNT CUT DURATION AFTER 55 seconds

#overwrite_output overwrites it automatically if i dont want it just use output
stream = ffmpeg.output(audio, video, r'C:\Users\johnc\Desktop\output.mp4')


ffmpeg.run(stream)
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a pair of shell scripts to handle my transcoding needs, including clipping out advertisements. I wanted to do millisecond precise clipping, and don't mind paying the price of reencoding.

- [transcode.sh](https://github.com/aaron-michaux/shell-scripts/blob/main/bin/transcode.sh) Handles transcoding, including extracting clips.
- [ff-segmenter.sh](https://github.com/aaron-michaux/shell-scripts/blob/main/bin/ff-segmenter.sh) A front-end where you can specify where the advertisements (or segments) start and stop.

Put both scripts on your path... and...

```
# Cut out everything from (3min 12.345s to 4min 1s) and (1hour 48min 0.2s to 1hour 52min 43.0s)
ff-segmenter.sh -i "input.mp4" -o "output.mp4" -x -s 3:12.345-4:01 -s 1:48:00.2-1:52:43
```

Without the `-x` switch, the selections are inverted. So everything outside the cut list is dropped. The `-h` switch explains.

Answer (score -6):

Even though I'm 6 years late, but I think all the answers above didn't properly address the question [@kalai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788891/kalai) is asking.
The bash script below will process a text file in the following format:

```sh
URL | start_time | end_time | filename
```

for example

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUDURCrvrMI|00:02:02|00:03:41|1
```

and loop through the file, downloads the file that `youtube-dl` supports, calculating duration between `start_time` and `end_time` and passing it to `ffmpeg`, since `-t` is actually the **duration**, not the real `end_time`

Hit me up if you have any question.

```sh
    for i in $(<video.txt);
    do
        URL=`echo $i | cut -d "|" -f 1`;
        START=`echo $i | cut -d "|" -f 2`;
        END=`echo $i | cut -d "|" -f 3`;
        FILE=`echo $i | cut -d "|" -f 4`;

        SEC1=`echo $START | sed 's/^/((/; s/:/)*60+/g' | bc`
        SEC2=`echo $END | sed 's/^/((/; s/:/)*60+/g' | bc`

        DIFFSEC=`expr ${SEC2} - ${SEC1}`

        ffmpeg $(youtube-dl -g $URL | sed "s/.*/-ss $START -i &/") -t $DIFFSEC -c copy $FILE".mkv";
        ffmpeg -i $FILE".mkv" -f mp3 -ab 192000 -vn $FILE".mp3";
        rm $FILE".mkv";
    done;
```

Comment: This outputs only an mp3 audio file and NOT a video.

Comment: I suppose you can update the script to output video format instead of audio. If I remember correctly, about 3 years ago I did it just for audio.