# Tool for XML based batch video processing anyone?

Tags: video, batch-processing

I have a long video and a database containing people IDs and the exact time each person shows up on the video.  I would like to generate small 6 second videos (starting 3 seconds before the person shows up and ending 3 seconds after that) but I'm looking for a tool that will let me do that automatically.  Thank you lots!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will have to write such a tool yourself. You can use ffmpeg for that as described on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444194/cutting-the-videos-based-on-start-and-end-time-using-ffmpeg)