# Working with video in android (crop, overlay, etc.) - how?

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg, android-camera

There was a task to create an application for Android that lets you record and work with video. There is no problem with recording video from a camera, but I ran into a problem processing videos. For example, you want to crop video, overlay audio, apply a few videos on each other ...

Are there any libraries that can help me achieve my goals? I was looking for some information on this issue, some people recommend using ffmpeg. Can ffmpeg library help me achieve what I described above?

I would be grateful for any information.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes ffmpeg is solution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the same,
[FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) library is the best solution available to your problem.
Its a lot it can do.

[Here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/useful-ffmpeg-commands/28490/) are few sample commands, but you'll get all of you mentioned above if your search on web.

**CROP:**
I dont know what do you mean by cropping,
But you can use these commands

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=out_w:out_h:x:y" out.mp4
```

for details check [this](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/4571)

OR

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -async 1 cut.mp4
```

[see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18449609/3828908) details

**OVERLAY AUDIO:**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.mp3 -c copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 output.mp4
```

check [this](https://superuser.com/a/590210)