# Using ffmpeg to obtain video durations in python

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I've installed ffprobe using the pip ffprobe command on my PC, and installed ffmpeg from [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html).

However, I'm still having trouble running the code listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844430/how-to-get-video-duration-in-python-or-django).

I try to use the following code unsuccessfully.

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file GetVideoDurations.py
on line 12, but no encoding declared; see
http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?  Am I not referencing the directories correctly?  Do I need to make sure the `.py` and video files are in a specific location?

```py
import subprocess

def getLength(filename):
    result = subprocess.Popen(["ffprobe", "filename"],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
    return [x for x in result.stdout.readlines() if "Duration" in x]

fileToWorkWith = ‪'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Video.mkv'

getLength(fileToWorkWith)
```

Apologies if the question is somewhat basic.  All I need is to be able to iterate over a group of video files and get their start time and end time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no need to iterate though the output of `FFprobe`. There is [one simple command](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Formatcontainerduration) which returns only the duration of the input file:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 <input_video>
```

You can use the following method instead to get the duration:

```
def get_length(input_video):
    result = subprocess.run(['ffprobe', '-v', 'error', '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-of', 'default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1', input_video], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return float(result.stdout)
```

Comment: @JavierC.H. don't use string formatting for making bash commands. If `input_video` is supplied by the user, you're letting them trivially run arbitrary bash commands from your Python code.

Comment: Is it possible to have it as HH:MM:SS format as output of `ffmpeg -i file.mkv 2>&1 | grep -o -P "(?<=Duration: ).*?(?=,)"`

Comment: For anyone getting a duration of `N/A`, maybe you need to repackage the file to add headers to it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40117749/1717535

Answer (score 13):

I'd suggest using FFprobe (comes with FFmpeg).

The answer Chamath gave was pretty close, but ultimately failed for me.

Just as a note, I'm using Python 3.5 and 3.6 and this is what worked for me.

```
import subprocess 

def get_duration(file):
    """Get the duration of a video using ffprobe."""
    cmd = 'ffprobe -i {} -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"'.format(file)
    output = subprocess.check_output(
        cmd,
        shell=True, # Let this run in the shell
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
    )
    # return round(float(output))  # ugly, but rounds your seconds up or down
    return float(output)
```

If you want to throw this function into a class and use it in Django (1.8 - 1.11), just change one line and put this function into your class, like so:

```
def get_duration(file):
```

to:

```
def get_duration(self, file):
```

**Note:** Using a relative path worked for me locally, but the production server required an absolute path. You can use `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(file))` to get the path to your video or audio file.

Comment: `shell=True` is not recommended

Answer (score 12):

Using the ffmpeg-python package (https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/)

```py
import ffmpeg
duration = ffmpeg.probe(local_file_path)["format"]["duration"]
```

where `local_file_path` is a relative or absolute path to your file.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Works under Python 3.9 and 3.11 and does not need subprocess output checking

Comment: This doesn't work for me: `AttributeError: module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'probe'
`

Comment: @SaeedEsmaili, my bad: it was ffmpeg-python (and not python-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 2):

I think Chamath's second comment answers the question: you have a strange character somewhere in your script, either because you are using a ` instead of a ' or you have a word with non-english accents, something like this.

As a remark, for what you are doing you can also try [MoviePy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy) which parses the ffmpeg output like you do (but maybe in the future I'll use Chamath's ffprobe method it looks cleaner):

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
duration =  mp.VideoFileClip("my_video.mp4").duration
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated solution using `ffprobe` based on @llogan guidance with the pointed [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22243834/2402577):

```
import subprocess

def get_duration(input_video):
    cmd = ["ffprobe", "-i", input_video, "-show_entries", "format=duration",
           "-v", "quiet", "-sexagesimal", "-of", "csv=p=0"]
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
```

---

#### Fragile Solution due to `stderr` output:

> the `stderr` output from `ffmpeg` is not intended for machine parsing and
> is considered fragile.

I get help from the following documentation (https://codingwithcody.com/2014/05/14/get-video-duration-with-ffmpeg-and-python/) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6239379/2402577

> Actually, sed is unnecessary: `ffmpeg -i file.mp4 2>&1 | grep -o -P "(?<=Duration: ).*?(?=,)"`

---

You can use the following method to get the duration in `HH:MM:SS` format:

```
import subprocess

def get_duration(input_video):
    # cmd: ffmpeg -i file.mkv 2>&1 | grep -o -P "(?<=Duration: ).*?(?=,)"
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg',  '-i', input_video], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep",  "-o", "-P", "(?<=Duration: ).*?(?=,)"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p1.stdout.close()
    return p2.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8").strip()
```

Example output for both: `01:37:11.83`

Comment: `grep` is unnecessary if you use ffprobe alone. For examples ee [How to extract duration time from ffmpeg output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22243834/) and [How to get video duration in seconds?](https://superuser.com/a/945604/). Also, the stderr output from ffmpeg is not intended for machine parsing and is considered fragile. That's what ffprobe is for.

Comment: @llogan: Thank you for your input. I have updated my answer based on your comment. I kept the old answer for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the encoding? That error is typical of that, as Chamath said.
Add the utf-8 encoding to your script header:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to build a shared library with ffmpeg, and load it in python.
C++ code:

```cpp
#ifdef __WIN32__
#define LIB_CLASS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIB_CLASS
#endif
extern "C" {
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
}
extern "C" LIB_CLASS int64_t getDur(const char* url) {
    AVFormatContext* pFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatContext, url, NULL, NULL)) {
        avformat_free_context(pFormatContext);
        return -1;
    }
    int64_t t = pFormatContext->duration;
    avformat_close_input(&pFormatContext);
    avformat_free_context(pFormatContext);
    return t;
}
```

Then use gcc to compile it and get a  shared library.
Python code:

```py
from ctypes import *
lib = CDLL('/the/path/to/your/library')
getDur = lib.getDur
getDur.restype = c_longlong
duration = getDur('the path/URL to your file')
```

It works well in my python program.

Answer (score -1):

Python Code

```
<code>
cmnd = ['/root/bin/ffmpeg',  '-i', videopath]
process = subprocess.Popen(cmnd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

#This matches regex to get the time in H:M:S format
matches = re.search(r"Duration:\s{1}(?P<hours>\d+?):(?P<minutes>\d+?):(?P<seconds>\d+\.\d+?),", stdout, re.DOTALL).groupdict()
t_hour = matches['hours']
t_min  = matches['minutes']
t_sec  = matches['seconds']

t_hour_sec = int(t_hour) * 3600
t_min_sec = int(t_min) * 60
t_s_sec   = int(round(float(t_sec)))

total_sec = t_hour_sec + t_min_sec + t_s_sec

#This matches1 is to get the frame rate of a video
matches1 = re.search(r'(\d+) fps', stdout)
frame_rate = matches1.group(0) // This will give 20fps
frame_rate = matches1.group(1) //It will give 20

</code>
```

Comment: Parsing the output from `ffmpeg` is fragile and is not designed to be used by scripts. Use `ffprobe` instead as shown in [Chamath's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31025482/1109017).

Comment: You should probably add an explanation as to what this is doing for people who are new with ffmpeg/ffprobe and Python.

Answer (score -2):

we can also use ffmpeg to get the duration of any video or audio files.

To install ffmpeg follow this [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)

```
import subprocess
import re

process = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg',  '-i', path_of_video_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
matches = re.search(r"Duration:\s{1}(?P<hours>\d+?):(?P<minutes>\d+?):(?P<seconds>\d+\.\d+?),", stdout, re.DOTALL).groupdict()

print (matches['hours'])
print (matches['minutes'])
print (matches['seconds'])
```

Comment: Parsing the output from `ffmpeg` is fragile and is not designed to be used by scripts. Use `ffprobe` instead as shown in [Chamath's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31025482/1109017).