# Get duration of an uploaded audio/video file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get the duration of audio/video files that are being uploaded into the system. Earlier I had used `hachoir-metadata`, but it's not maintained anymore I guess, as there is no python 3 compatible module for that.

- IS there any other light weight alternative to it?
- In case if I wish to write something of my own to do it, what would be the prerequisites?

Comment: If you have ffmpeg installed you can use ffprobe, as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31025482/4014959); it should work on any audio or video file that ffmpeg supports, which is just about everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know about `ffmpeg`, you can use ffmpeg to read the audio or video, it will output the duration of audio or video

```
$ ffmpeg -i  "Gotye - Somebody That I Used To Know (feat. Kimbra) - official video.mp4" 2>&1 | grep -E -o "Duration: \S+" 
Duration: 00:04:03.90,
```

Comment: Got this `*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.` after trying it. So tried, avconv it works

Comment: thanks for ffmpeg answer led me to a working solution. ;)

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar, if that works for you , you can accept my answer.

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar: FWIW, that deprecation warning is a little misleading. See [the Wikipedia article on Libav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libav) for details.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the link, I saw the deprecation warning hence mentioned it and went ahead with avconv

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this particular thing, follow following steps:

- Make sure you have libav-tools package installed. You can check it by typing and trying to execute `avconv` command. If not present, do `sudo apt-get install libav-tools`
- Then, try this command `ffmpeg -i myvideo 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//` (I found this command [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224237/how-to-check-how-long-a-video-mp4-is-using-the-shell)).
- If you want to use it in python script, you can probably use subprocess module to your effect

Correct me if I am wrong somewhere