# Cut a video in between key frames without re-encoding the full video using ffpmeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I would like to cut a video at the beginning at any particular timestamp, and it need to be **precise**, so the nearest key frame is not good enough.

Also, these videos are rather long - an hour or longer - so I would like to **avoid re-encoding** this altogether if possible, or otherwise only re-encode a minimal fraction of the total duration. Thus, would like to maximise the use of `-vcodec copy`.

How can I accomplish this using `ffmpeg`?

NOTE: See scenario, and my own rough idea for a possible solution below.

---

Scenario:

- Original video

  - Length of 1:00:00
  - Has a key frame every 10s
- Desired cut:

  - From 0:01:35 through till the end
- Attempt #1:

  - Using `-ss 0:01:35 -i blah.mp4 -vcodec copy`, what results is a file where:
  - audio starts at 0:01:30
  - video also starts at 0:01:30
  - this starts both the audio and the video too early
- using `-i blah.mp4 -ss 0:01:35 -vcodec copy`, what results is a file where:

  - audio starts at 0:01:35,
  - but the video is blank/ black for the first 5 seconds,

    - until 0:01:40, when the video starts
  - this starts the audio on time,
    but the video starts too late

---

Rough idea

- (1) cut 0:01:30 to 0:01:40

  - re-encode this to have new key frames,
    including one at the target time of 0:01:35
  - then cut this to get the 5 seconds from 0:01:35 through 0:01:40
- (2) cut 0:01:40 through till the end

  - without re-encoding, using `-vcodec copy`
- (3) `ffmpeg concat` the first short clip (the 5 second one)
  with the second long clip

I know/ can work out the commands for (2) and (3), but am unsure about what commands are needed for (1).

Comment: Note that using edit lists with mp4 container is not an option in my case because of target video players, as well as subsequent steps that I have in post-processing this video

Comment: This can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444194/cutting-the-videos-based-on-start-and-end-time-using-ffmpeg

Comment: For specifying the keyframe interval (GOP size), use the `-g` flag.
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites

Answer (score 21, accepted):

List timestamps of key frames:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -skip_frame nokey -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -of csv=p=0 input.mp4
```

It will output something like:

```
0.000000
2.502000
3.795000
6.131000
10.344000
12.554000
16.266000
...
```

Let's say you want to delete timestamps 0 to 5, and then [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the remainder. The closest following key frame is 6.131.

Re-encode 5 to 6.131. Ensure the input and output match attributes and formats. For MP4 default settings should do most of the work, assuming H.264/AAC, but you may have to [manually match the profile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Profile).

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 5 -to 6.131 trimmed.mp4
```

Make `input.txt` for the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

```
file 'trimmed.mp4'
file 'input.mp4'
inpoint 6.131
```

Concatenate:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

Comment: this looks like something that fits what I'm asking. I followed the link to matching the profile in your answer, but couldn't work out how to use that. what would your `ffmpeg` command that outputs the trimmed file be when doing that. something like `-v:profile copy` perhaps?

Comment: @bguiz Look at input with ffmpeg and look for `Video: h264 (High)`. The `()` may contain Baseline or Main instead of High. If that's the case add `-profile:v main` or `-profile:v baseline`. You don't need to do anything extra if it is High. Or use ffprobe to find profile: `ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=profile -of csv=p=0 input.mp4`. Not all formats have profiles.

Comment: What the difference with: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 5.0 -to <last_time> output.mp4` ?

Comment: should `input.mp4` in the final commandline be `input.txt`?

Comment: I know the question was only about video, I wanted audio too and I was having trouble following the instructions because I always ended up with broken audio after the first re-encoded part. The reason was that I was re-encoding the audio too, changing its format to something incompatible with the original. Adding `-c:a copy` when re-encoding the first part solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

try

```sh
ffmpeg -i src.mp4 -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 out.mp4
```

or

```sh
ffmpeg -i src.mp4 -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 src_.m3u8
```

which generates hls playlists