# Using ffmpeg to replace a single frame by number of frame from a video

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to replace only one frame from my video (mp4) and if possible without re-encode.

I have extracted all frames of my video and I see the frame to replace is number 45 (frame0045.png for example).

I ask if is possible replace a single frame by number of frame.

Thanks !

Comment: Method depends on the format of the input video.

Comment: the format is mp4.

Comment: It's not trivial. You have to: 1) Identify timestamps of keyframes. 2) Choose the section between keyframes that contains the desired timestamp. 3) Re-encode that section and overlay the new frame using `enable` option. Make sure this re-encoded section has the same attributes as the original file for proper concatenation. 4) Concatenate. See [Cut a video in between key frames without re-encoding the full video using ffmoeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63604858/) for a basic idea of the method that you may be able to adapt.

Comment: Thank you ! I will try.