Split a video with ffmpeg, without reencoding, at timestamps given in a txt file
Let's say we have a video input.mp4, and a file split.csv containing:
start;end;name
00:00:27.132;00:07:42:422;"Part A.mp4"
00:07:48.400;00:17:17.921;"Part B.mp4"

(or I could format the text file in any other format)
How to split the MP4 into different parts with the given start / end timestamps, and the given filename for each part?
Is it possible directly with ffmpeg, and if not with a Python script?

Done, thanks @NotTheDr01ds!

Note that if you want to split at completely arbitrary points in a typical video (encoded prioritizing small output over seek performance, robustness against transmission errors, and [typically] quality), some reencoding is unavoidable -- if the new first frame was differential in the original it needs to be reencoded to be an iframe (standalone/complete), or the start point can be adjusted to the nearest iframe instead of the point originally provided.

@CharlesDuffy Yes, I also noticed that here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78743963/when-extracting-a-part-of-a-video-with-ffmpeg-without-reencoding-the-output-is). How would you deal with this task (just splitting a video, with minimal reencoding) in a simple way?

Depends on the requirements, but if they allow I'd snap to the nearest keyframe, just as the answer to the question you link suggests. Barring that, reencoding only the frames between the current location and the next keyframe, copying from that next keyframe, and then concatenating the two videos together are all steps for which recipes are available.

Thanks @CharlesDuffy. Isn't there nowadays just a flag like ffmpeg -ss 60 -t 10 -snaptonearestkeyframe? It seems complicated to have to use multiple calls of ffmpeg, Would you have command-line or script example to snap to nearest keyframes?

PS @CharlesDuffy: I have started a +250 bounty here about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63548027/cut-a-video-in-between-key-frames-without-re-encoding-the-full-video-using-ffpme if you have an idea for a ready-to-use way to do this ;)

Hmm -- I didn't know you could put a bounty on a closed question. Going to be a little tricky to actually add any answers there. (Not something that impacts me immediately, though: I don't have one readymade, and if I do get a chance to try to put an answer together it'll need to be outside work hours).

@CharlesDuffy Oh, I see it has been closed just after I put the bounty :)

I finally found a working answer:
import csv, subprocess
INPUT_FILE = "input.mp4"
CSV_FILE = "split.csv"
FFMPEG_PATH = r"D:\misc\ffmpeg.exe"
with open(CSV_FILE, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        start = row['start']
        end = row['end']
        output_file = row['name']
        start_time = sum(float(x) * 60 ** i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(start.split(":"))))
        end_time = sum(float(x) * 60 ** i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(end.split(":"))))
        duration = end_time - start_time
        output_file = output_file.replace("'", "\'")
        output_file = f"{output_file}.mp4"
        command = [FFMPEG_PATH, '-y', '-i', INPUT_FILE, '-ss', start, '-t', str(duration), '-vcodec', 'copy', '-acodec', 'copy', output_file]
        subprocess.run(command)

Note that it's important to escape output_file to avoid having ' in it.
