# How to cut videos automatically using Python with FFmpeg?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm trying to cut videos automatically using Python with FFmpeg so I don't have to type out the command everytime I want a new video cut. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong though, here's the code:

import os

```
path = r'C:/Users/user/Desktop/folder'

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
       if (filename.endswith(".mp4")): 
           command = "ffmpeg - i" + filename + "-c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:00:06 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 output%03d.mp4"
           os.system(command)
       else:
           continue
```

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: nothing happens! I'm also not sure the syntax of the command being "+ filename + " is right.

Answer (score 2):

## Typos

First of all, there's a typo in the syntax, as you wrote `- i` while the correct syntax is `-i`.
The syntax `" + filename + "` is correct, however there must be a space before and after

```py
command = "ffmpeg -i " + filename + " -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:00:06 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 output%03d.mp4"
```

otherwise, you would get an error like

```
Unrecognized option 'iC:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\filename.mp4-c'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

## Solution

I assumed every other argument is correct, for me it didn't work at first, I just had to add
`-fflags +discardcorrupt`
but maybe it's just my file.

Here's the correct code, however I recommend to you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444194/cutting-the-videos-based-on-start-and-end-time-using-ffmpeg).

Note: I used `os.path.join()` to save the output file in that same directory  because my python file was in another one.

```py
import os

path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".mp4"): 
        command = "ffmpeg -fflags +discardcorrupt -i " + os.path.join(path, filename) + " -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:00:03 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 " + os.path.join(path, "output%03d.mp4")
        os.system(command)
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cut a video file with ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:03:20 -t 00:10:24 out.mpt
```

`-ss` : start_time

`-to` : end_time

`-t` : duration_time