# Node.js: Is it possible to extract sub-clips from a broader video file based on start/stop time stamps?

Tags: node.js, video, backend, extract

I have a flow where iOS app users will record a large video file and upload it to our server. After the fact, the user might want to extract certain portions of that larger video based on specific time stamps and generate a highlight reel that can be viewed and shared locally back on the iOS device.

As a FE developer I don't really have much experience with where to even start here. Our BE will be built in NodeJS. It seems to me that this should be a relatively straightforward problem to solve, but I don't know.

Are there APIs that make movie manipulation easy? Can I easily extract a clip based on a start and stop time and save that as a separate file? Are those costly tasks? Or not too bad?

I'm guessing that the response to this call would be a list of a series of file names that have been generated as a result of these clips being generated, that the iOS app could then pull down and load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite as straightforward as it might seem as video files are quite structured with header information and indexing into the individual video and audio tracks and frames. Any splitting up or cropping needs to allow for this and also create new files with the correct headers and indexing etc.

Fortunately, there are indeed libraries that you can use to do this type of thing, one of the most powerful being ffmpeg.

There are projects which allow the ffmpeg command line tool be used programatically - the advantage of this approach is that you get to leverage the vast community knowledge base for ffmpeg command line.

One of the popular ones for nodejs is:

- https://github.com/damianociarla/node-ffmpeg

You can then look at the ffmpeg documentation or community answers to find the particularly functionality you need - for example to crop video at a start and end time as you asked:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42827058/334402
- https://superuser.com/a/704118

The general idea is quite simple and will be of the format:

> ffmpeg -i yourInputVideo.mp4 -ss 01:30:00 -to 02:30:00 -c copy copy yourNewOutputVideo.mp4

It's worth taking a look at the seeking info in the ffmpeg online documentation (https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) to help understand the examples, especially the second one above:

> -ss position (input/output)
> When used as an input option (before -i), seeks in this input file to position. Note that in most formats it is not possible to seek exactly, so ffmpeg will seek to the closest seek point before position. When transcoding and -accurate_seek is enabled (the default), this extra segment between the seek point and position will be decoded and discarded. When doing stream copy or when -noaccurate_seek is used, it will be preserved.

> When used as an output option (before an output url), decodes but discards input until the timestamps reach position.

> position must be a time duration specification, see (ffmpeg-utils)the Time duration section in the ffmpeg-utils(1) manual.