# How to split Y4M video file into multiple Y4M files using FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm working on a Transcoding video project and I need to split a video file into multiple files.

Input file is in `Y4M` format.

Output files are also in `Y4M` format with `8` frames per video file.

How can I do it using `ffmpeg`?

Comment: Use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005110/how-to-split-a-video-using-ffmpeg-so-that-each-chunk-starts-with-a-key-frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005110/how-to-split-a-video-using-ffmpeg-so-that-each-chunk-starts-with-a-key-frame)

Comment: thanks @Rotem I will try do so.

Comment: I'm back to you, What i didn't mention in the question, is that I'm working with rawvideo, the link you give it to me work only with other video container. Can you help me with this ?@Rotem

Comment: GOP is not well defined for raw video. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures). Please explain what do you mean by "split the video into GOPs". Do you mean group of raw video frames, or group of compressed video frames starting with I - Frame (key frame)?

Comment: Well, what I want to do is encode a rawvideo(Y4m) with libx265 using Ffmpeg but in parallel mode, for that I need to split(segment) the input into several segment so that each node encode a segment.
The segment is defined by a number of frames.

Comment: So all you need (for now) is splitting the large Y4m into multiple small Y4m files, with 8 frames per "small" file?

Comment: Yes that exactly what I need.

Comment: I found a solution using `ffmpeg`. I edited your question to match your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution (using `ffmpeg`).

The following example creates sample input file (for testing), and split it into parts.
In my example, the input file contains 8 frames per second, and the splitting process creates one output file for each second.
(I tried using option `-segment_frames 8` instead of `-segment_time 1`, but it's not working).

Create input file (for testing):
Create `AVI` file and convert `AVI` file into `y4m` format file:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:size=160x120:rate=8 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -y input.avi
ffmpeg -i input.avi -pix_fmt yuv444p input.y4m
```

Split file into segments of 8 frames (1 second per video file):

For Windows (use `%%`):

```
ffmpeg -i input.y4m -f segment -segment_time 1 -pix_fmt yuv444p output%%4d.y4m
```

For Linux (use `%`):

```
ffmpeg -i input.y4m -f segment -segment_time 1 -pix_fmt yuv444p output%4d.y4m
```

Comment: So your solution is to change the frame rate of the video than split it, could that have an effect on the quality of the video ?

Comment: I tried the command for linux, it worked perfectly in the terminal, but when I use it on matlab 
 
`function [] = segmenting(dir)`
    `cd(dir);`
    `videoNameIn = 'galleon_422_cif';`
    `videoNameOut = 'segment';`
    `videoType = '.y4m';`
    `segmentTime = 1;`
    `pix_fmt = 'yuv422p';`
    `system(['ffmpeg -i ', videoNameIn, videoType, ' -f segment -segment_time ', num2str(segmentTime), ' -pix_fmt ', pix_fmt , videoNameOut,'%3d',videoType]);`
`end`


I got an error :

`At least one output file must be specified`

Comment: You don't need to change the frame rate, you can use fractions of seconds. Example: `ffmpeg -i input.y4m -f segment -segment_time 0.5 -pix_fmt yuv444p output%4d.y4m`. Set `-segment_time` parameter to **8/framerate**

Comment: About the error: You missed a `space` after `yuv422p`. It should be: `system(['ffmpeg -i ', videoNameIn, videoType, ' -f segment -segment_time ', num2str(segmentTime), ' -pix_fmt ', pix_fmt, ' ', videoNameOut,'%3d',videoType]);`

Comment: You should learn how to debug your own code... without the space you are getting `yuv422psegment001.y4m` instead of `yuv422p segment001.y4m`...

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate it.