# Is it possible to use FFmpeg to cut "random" sections from a folder of videos and concat them into 1 video?

Tags: python, linux, bash, video, ffmpeg

I realize this sounds like an easy question, and one that has been answered before. However, I cannot seem to find a script which can read a folder of videos with varying lengths, copy a random segment from each video, and concat them into a single video.

An example:

I have a folder with 150 videos labeled Fashion-Setlist-01.mp4, Fashion-Setlist-02.mp4, etc.
Each are over 1 hour. I would like to pull a random 10 seconds section from each video and then randomly add them together resulting in a video. This may seem easy with only a few videos, but the plan is to read from potentially 100's of videos. It should be possible to pull multiple sections from each video as well. I suppose we could run the script twice for more segments if the video needed to be longer.

Comment: I think this kind of problem would usually be solved by writing a pipeline from scratch. By pipeline, I don't (necessarily) mean bash pipeline, I mean a sequence of scripts which each perform an intermediate step and store the output in a temporary directory. Later scripts in the sequence will work on whatever intermediate/temporary files they find. This helps break it down into manageable steps. Eg first you create a script that just does the one task of grabbing a random slice of video from a filename argument and store it in a temporary directory. A makefile could coordinate the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[moviepy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) is the most appropriate tool for this (it uses ffmpeg as a backend). Concatenating videos is trivial in moviepy:

```
import moviepy.editor
import os
import random
import fnmatch 

directory = '/directory/to/videos/'
xdim = 854
ydim = 480
ext = "*mp4"
length = 10

outputs=[]

# compile list of videos
inputs = [os.path.join(directory,f) for f in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, f)) and fnmatch.fnmatch(f, ext)]

for i in inputs:

    # import to moviepy
    clip = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip(i).resize( (xdim, ydim) ) 

    # select a random time point
    start = round(random.uniform(0,clip.duration-length), 2) 

    # cut a subclip
    out_clip = clip.subclip(start,start+length)

    outputs.append(out_clip)

# combine clips from different videos
collage = moviepy.editor.concatenate_videoclips(outputs) 

collage.write_videofile('out.mp4')
```

Comment: Thanks @hb_ ! I will give this a shot.

Comment: EDIT*** This works great!! It's doing exactly what I need. 1 question though, does it pull more than 1 subclip from each video? It's not a big deal if it doesn't, I'm just curious.

Comment: glad to help. the code above pulls one clip from each video, but if you need another you can just duplicate the lines within the for loop. Or, a more dynamic solution would be to put it in a while loop with the minimum total length you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Cutting video with ffmpeg needs to be done on a key-frame.  I extensively edited this code to first find the key-frames, then cut around this.  It works for me.

So to do this in `bash`, assuming there exists some program `randtime.py` which outputs a random starting time in 'H:MM:SS' format, and some other program which finds the video keyframe near a given time, here's a quick hack-version:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

CUTLIST=cut_list.txt
RANDTIME=~/Bin/randtime.py
KEYFRAMER=~/Bin/find_next_key_frame.py

count=0
echo "" > "$CUTLIST"
for file in *.mp4
do
    count=$(( $count + 1 ));
    outfile="cut_$count.mp4"
    start_time=`python "$RANDTIME"`
    # Find the next keyframe, at or after the random time
    start_keyframe_time=`$KEYFRAMER "$file" "$start_time"`
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Nearest keyframe to \"$start_time\" is \"$start_keyframe_time\""
        echo "ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -y -i \"$file\" -ss $start_keyframe_time -t 00:00:10 \"$outfile\""
        ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -y -i "$file" -ss $start_keyframe_time -t 00:00:10 "$outfile"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "ffmpeg returned an error on [$file], aborting"
        #   exit 1
        fi
        echo "file '$outfile'" >> "$CUTLIST"
    else
        echo "ffprobe found no suitable key-frame near \"$start_time\""
    fi
done

echo "Concatenating ... "
cat "$CUTLIST"

ffmpeg -f concat -i cut_list.txt -c copy all_cuts.mp4

if [ -f "$CUTLIST" ]; then
    rm "$CUTLIST"
fi
```

And the random time, in `python`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import random

#TODO: ensure we're at least 8 seconds before 1 hour

hrs = 0 # random.randint(0,1)
mns = random.randint(0,59)
scs = random.randint(0,59)

print("%d:%02d:%02d" % (hrs,mns,scs))
```

And, and again in `python` find the keyframe exactly on, or just after the time given.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import subprocess
import os
import os.path

FFPROBE='/usr/bin/ffprobe'

EXE=sys.argv[0].replace('\\','/').split('/')[-1]

if (not os.path.isfile(FFPROBE)):
    sys.stderr.write("%s: The \"ffprobe\" part of FFMPEG seems to be missing\n" % (EXE))
    sys.exit(1)

if (len(sys.argv) == 1 or (len(sys.argv)==2 and sys.argv[1] in ('--help', '-h', '-?', '/?'))):
    sys.stderr.write("%s: Give video filename and time as arguments\n" % (EXE))
    sys.stderr.write("%s:     e.g.: video_file.mp4 0:25:14 \n" % (EXE))
    sys.stderr.write("%s: Outputs the next keyframe at or after the given time\n" % (EXE))
    sys.exit(1)

VIDEO_FILE = sys.argv[1]
FRAME_TIME = sys.argv[2].strip()

if (not os.path.isfile(VIDEO_FILE)):
    sys.stderr.write("%s: The vdeo file \"%s\" seems to be missing\n" % (EXE, VIDEO_FILE))
    sys.exit(1)


### Launch FFMPEG's ffprobe to identify the frames
command = "ffprobe -show_frames -pretty \"%s\"" % VIDEO_FILE
frame_list = subprocess.getoutput(command)

### The list of frames is a huge bunch of lines like:
###    [FRAME]
###    media_type=video
###    key_frame=0
###    best_effort_timestamp=153088
###    best_effort_timestamp_time=0:00:09.966667
###    pkt_duration_time=0:00:00.033333
###    height=360
###    ...
###    [/FRAME]

### Parse the stats about each frame, keeping only the Video Keyframes
key_frames = []
for frame in frame_list.split("[FRAME]"):
    # split the frame lines up into separate "x=y" pairs
    frame_dict = {}
    frame_vars = frame.replace('\r', '\n').replace("\n\n", '\n').split('\n')
    for frame_pair in frame_vars:
        if (frame_pair.find('=') != -1):
            try:
                var,value = frame_pair.split('=', 1)
                frame_dict[var.strip()] = value.strip()
            except:
                sys.stderr.write("%s: Warning: Unable to parse [%s]\n" % (EXE, frame_pair))
        # Do we want to keep this frame?
        # we want video frames, that are key frames
        if ("media_type", "key_frame" in frame_dict and frame_dict["media_type"] == "video" and frame_dict["key_frame"] == "1"):
            key_frames.append(frame_dict)

### Throw away duplicates, ans sort (why are there duplicates?)
key_frame_list = set()
for frame_dict in key_frames:        
    #print(str(frame_dict))
    if ("best_effort_timestamp_time" in frame_dict):
        key_frame_list.add(frame_dict["best_effort_timestamp_time"])
key_frame_list = list(key_frame_list)
key_frame_list.sort()
sys.stderr.write("Keyframes found: %u, from %s -> %s\n" % (len(key_frame_list), key_frame_list[0], key_frame_list[-1]))

### Find the same, or next-larger keyframe
found = False
for frame_time in key_frame_list:
    #sys.stderr.write("COMPARE %s > %s\n" % (frame_time , FRAME_TIME))
    if (frame_time > FRAME_TIME):
        print(frame_time)
        found = True
        break  # THERE CAN BE ONLY ONE!

### Failed?  Print something possibly useful
if (found == False):
    sys.stderr.write("%s: Warning: No keyframe found\n" % (EXE))
    print("0:00:00")
    sys.exit(-1)
else:
    sys.exit(0)  # All'swell
```

Comment: This does not start the cut a video key-frames, this would give a nicer output I think.  See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005110/how-to-split-a-video-using-ffmpeg-so-that-each-chunk-starts-with-a-key-frame/14013439#14013439

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ran into this though.   


"Input #0, concat, from 'cut_list.txt': 
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A 
Output #0, mp4, to 'all_cuts.mp4': 
Output file #0 does not contain any stream"'

EDIT: It appears only 4 of the files have video in them. The rest are roughly 464 bytes each.

Comment: @EmmyStrand - It looks like ffmpeg can only cut at a key-frame (or suchlike).  Maybe there's an option to tell ffmpeg to start cutting at the next key-frame after the given time, but if there is I don't know if it, so I brute-forced it.  The `find_next_key_frame.py` takes a while to run.  It's suboptimal.

Comment: Thanks!! I think it works. How hard would it be to adjust the code so it makes 2 random cuts per mp4? Or would it be easier to run the script twice and just not concat the first run?

Comment: @EmmyStrand - If you specify the same files in the input file set twice, it will make two cuts from each file.  It's random though, so they might overlap ;)

Comment: When transcoding, the `ss` does not need to point to a keyframe.

Comment: @Gyan - I believe you, but if it didn't start with a keyframe, ffmpeg did not produce a valid video file.  As soon as the start-time corresponded to a keyframe, every output was correct.

Comment: @Kingsley  Share command, full log and the invalid output file if you can.

Comment: @Gyan - as per the bash script above, but just starting with a random timestamp.  I tested over 4 copies of the same video file, and as the OP found too, randomly FFmpeg would produce a valid 10-second video file, or a ~400 byte file.  I changed the script to first find the keyframe nearest the random timestamp, use that for the start-time instead, and then all output video files were valid.

Comment: If your random timestamp is greater than the duration of the video or some other argument is invalid, then ffmpeg will abort after writing a partial output file header. This is not related to the starting point being a KF or not.